# WebStorm - Typescript Getter for readonly properties - No fields without getter and setter have been found

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I tried to generate getter methods for the follwoing class:

```
export class v{
  private readonly _a:number;
  private readonly _b;
  private readonly _c:number;
  private readonly _d:string;

  constructor(a:number, b, c:number,d:string){
      this._a=a;
      this._b=b;
      this._c=c;
      this._d=d;
  }
}
```

But Webstorm prints the following error: *No fields without getter and setter have been found*`

If a add a non `readonly` property to the class (e.g. `private _e:string;`), Webstorm will be able to generate getter/setter for this property.

Is this a bug of Webstorm or is it not possible to generate getter methods for readonly properties of a class?

---

**UPDATE**

In this [MWE](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20V%7B%0D%0A%20%20private%20readonly%20_a%3Anumber%3B%0D%0A%20%20private%20readonly%20_b%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20get%20b()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this._b%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(a%3Anumber%2C%20b)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this._a%3Da%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this._b%3Db%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20testObject%20%3D%20new%20V(123%2C%20%22test%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(testObject.b)%3B) you can see that it is possible to define getter for a `private readonly` property.

```
class V{
  private readonly _a:number;
  private readonly _b;

  get b(): string {
    return this._b;
  }

  constructor(a:number, b){
      this._a=a;
      this._b=b;
  }
}

var testObject = new V(123, "test");

console.log(testObject.b);
```

Comment: If a propery is readonly, you can't write to it, so you can't set a value to it. Just Typescript. Either set a `readonly` property in constructor, or use a `private` (or `protected`) with a getter and a setter. You could also try a `private` getter and setter.

Comment: I know that i can't write to a `readonly` property. But I can read it and therefore why shouldn't I create a getter for this `readonly` property??

Comment: @hlfrmn Constructing objects of class `v` works with the constructor above.

Comment: I see, it makes sense that you should be able to declare a getter. Doesn't work in my WebStorm either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently a bug in WebStorm.

See [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30078)